# How to make a div take the remaining height of parent container

Tags: css, flexbox

I know this has been asked before, but I could not find any solution that works.

I need the div with class .height to take the remaining height of the parent

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <main>
      <v-content>
        <v-container fluid grid-list-xs>
          <v-layout row wrap>
            <v-flex xs6>
              <v-toolbar></v-toolbar>
              <div class="height"></div>
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex xs2></v-flex>
            <v-flex xs4></v-flex>
          </v-layout>
        </v-container>
      </v-content>
    </main>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.height {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

CODEPEN link
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bYGeMN

Why is not the display flex + height 100% working?

I'm using the Vuetify library to get a material design theme on VueJS, but I think this question is not related to VueJS but CSS.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the `v-container` and `v-layout` will have their height set to 100%. Also, the `display: flex` and `flex-flow: column` need to be set on `xs6` not the inner `div`:

```
.container, .layout {
  height: 100%;
}

.xs6 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.height {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```